# double printing of instance variables on HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I'm following this tutorial (http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#sec:signup_form). However, when code in **Listing 7.23** (converted to haml)

```
=if @user.errors.any?
%div{:id => "error_explanation"}
  %div{:class=>"alert alert-error"}
    il modulo contiene errori
    %ul
      = @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
        %li
          = msg
```

I end up with a double printout: the expected one, followed by a sort of printout of the variables

```
Name can't be blank
Password is too long (maximum is 15 characters)
["Name can't be blank", "Password is too long (maximum is 15 characters)"]
<h1>Registrazione nuovo utente</h1> <div id='error_explanation'> <div class='alert alert-error'> il modulo contiene errori <ul> <li> Name can't be blank </li> <li> Password is too long (maximum is 15 characters) </li> [&quot;Name can't be blank&quot;, &quot;Password is too long (maximum is 15 characters)&quot;]</ul> </div> </div>
```

I'm really new to rails programming, but I really can't get.

Thanks, Marcello

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` statement should start with a `-`, not a `=`:

```
- if @user.errors.any?
```

And your loop should too:

```
- @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
```

Generally, if you're trying to convert from erb to haml, `<% ... %>` becomes `- ...` and `<%= ... %>` becomes `= ...`

Comment: Thanks. I should pay more attention!